# Some apps don't open in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation, xorg, gnome-software

How can I fix it? Some apps are Ubuntu Software and Postman. I tried to remove postman and reinstall it again, logout and log back in by choosing Ubuntu and Xorg, but it also didn't work.
Even i used another ubuntu account i didn't work

Comment: In such case, I open the terminal and try to start it from there. Error messages may be displayed in the terminal that may hint to the cause of the problem. Another idea is to temporarily create a new account and see if the issue reproduces when logging in to the now account. This allows to see whether the problem is system wide or tied to a specific user account. Why did you tag your post with "server"?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Is it snap package?